# Keeping Java files in packages during compilation

Tags: java, eclipse, package, buildpath

In my Java class, I would like to output the code of another (uncompiled) Java class of the same project. This is the package structure:

```
main (package)
   files (package)
      SampleClass.java
      SampleFile.txt
CodeOutput.java
```

And the code of `CodeOutput.java`:

```
public class CodeOutput {
    public void run() {
        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("files/SampleClass.java");
        BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        try {
            System.out.println(stream.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CodeOutput().run();
    }
}
```

I try to load the file `SampleClass.java` from the `files` package and output its first line. However, the Java file doesn't remain in the package after compilation. I also tried to exclude the file from the build path (in the file's context menu: Build Path -> Exclude), so the code isn't compiled to a `.class` file, but still the Java file doesn't appear in the package. It works fine with the `SampleFile.txt`, so I'm sure it has something to do with the project/build path settings.

Any ideas how to treat Java files like other resources in a package?

Comment: Are you wanting to include the source for all of the files? You can declare `src/main/java` as a resource directory (and at least used to have to do this with GWT).

Comment: Not all the files in the project, but all files inside a package (and its sub-packages) would be fine. How can I declare them as a resource directory?

Comment: How are you building this? It's pretty easy with Maven (and I think Gradle), but I don't know about fiddling with it manually in Eclipse.

Comment: Just plain Eclipse. Unfortunately, I can't use anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will compile all .java files under `src/main/java`. If you wish not to compile a java file, keep it under `/src/main/resources`. Also if you're using maven to build your source code, you can easily include source code in the jar file. [Instructions here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: There is no `src/main/java` folder in my project. It's just an `src` folder containing the packages and files listed above. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, and I don't use Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new directory outside your java source and add that directory to your class path. You can create the same package structure under that directory. So CodeOutput would be a compilable java class, but all files added under the new directory in your class path will not.

If you don't want to do that, you cannot access ur source files the way u r trying to access them now.

Comment: Ok, that might work. But how do I add the new folder to the classpath?

Comment: Create a directory in eclipse.. Right click on the project go to properties.. In the classpath select the folder and add into the classpath